# JavaScript String Object to String

Tags: javascript, stringify

In node.js the next code

```
var Reverse = (function() {

    return {
        reverse1: function(s) {
            var out = new String();
            for (var i = s.length - 1, j = 0; i >= 0; i--, j++) {
                out[j] = s[i];
            }
            return out;
        }
    }
})();

console.log(Reverse.reverse1("this is text"));
```

prints

```
{ '0': 't',
  '1': 'x',
  '2': 'e',
  '3': 't',
  '4': ' ',
  '5': 's',
  '6': 'i',
  '7': ' ',
  '8': 's',
  '9': 'i',
  '10': 'h',
  '11': 't' 
}
```

But I want to print a string. I've tried `return out.toString()` but returns nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you have a real serious reason to need this done by array index, why not just concatenate onto it?

```
out += s[i];
```

Will print:

```
// "txet si siht"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use join method of array.

```
 return out.join('');
```

And change `var out = new String();` to `var out = [];`

***And Note:***

You could do the below to reverse a string:

```
var ret = "this is text".split('').reverse().join('');
```

Comment: @enrmarc And change `new String()` to `[]`

Comment: Thanks, I know `reverse` and `split` but I have to use only pure code: http://www.cocode.co/index.php?qa=67&qa_1=reversing-strings

Answer (score 1):

```
var Reverse = (function() {
    return {
        reverse1: function(s) {
            var out = "";
            for (var i = s.length - 1, j = 0; i >= 0; i--, j++) out += s[i];
            return out;
        }
    };
})();
console.log(Reverse.reverse1("this is text"));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var Reverse = (function() {

    return {
        reverse1: function(s) {
            out = '';
            for (var i = s.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                out += s[i];
            }
            return out;
        }
    }
})();

console.log(Reverse.reverse1("this is text"));
```